# How to read the file and print it in array properly?

Tags: c, file

I was wondering why it's keep on printing number 1 even though I got no number 1 in my file

```
The input file is: file.in
2
4 
0 0 0 0

FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("file.in","r");

if(fp != NULL)
{
    fscanf(fp, "%d\n", &noOfPuzzles);
    fscanf(fp, "%d\n", &dimensionOfBoard);
    int position[dimensionOfBoard];
    int value[dimensionOfBoard];
    for(i = 0 ; i< dimensionOfBoard; i++)
     {
            position[i] = fscanf(fp, "%d ", &value[i]);
     } 
}

printf("No. of Puzzles: %d\n",noOfPuzzles);
printf("Dimension of Board: %d\n",dimensionOfBoard);
for(i = 0 ; i< dimensionOfBoard; i++)
     {
             printf("%d ",position[i]);
     } 



 The output is always like this:
 No. of Puzzles: 2
 Dimension of Board: 4
 1 1 1 1
```

How come that it keeps on printing number '1'? Thank you

Comment: `position[i] = fscanf(...)` : on success, fscanf returns the number of items in the argument list successfully read, which would always be `1` in this case.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is catching the return value of fscanf():

```
        position[i] = fscanf(fp, "%d ", &value[i]);
```

You're storing 1 in position[i] because fscanf() returns 1 to indicate that it populated 1 value - you're reading the actual value to value[i] then outputting the value in position[i]

```
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &position[i]);
```

Will work, output the values of the value[] array in the last loop.

Comment: Thank you so much guys.I'm printing the wrong array. :)))

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the return value of `fscanf()` to `position[i]`, which returns how many values it successfully populated or −1 if an error occured.

Rather, you need to use the `values[i]` array to print the zeroes you read from file.

Comment: False. `fscanf()` does not return if it is successful or not. It returns the number of items that were scanned, which is more than a mere “pass/fail” result.

Comment: Thanks..fixed in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of `fscanf` is incorrect. `fscanf` returns the number of items it successfully scanned, which is 1 item in your case, thus assigning `1` to every member of `position`. I don't know what the purpose of the `value` array is, but you could scan directly into `position` like this:

```
fscanf(fp, "%d ", &position[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are printing out position[i], which you have set to the return value of fscanf. Fscanf places the read value into its second argument in this case and returns the number of characters read. You need to print out values[i] instead.